# Speeding up repeated generation of Exponential random variables in loop

Tags: r, performance, random, rcpp

I am implementing an algorithm, and as part of that, I need to generate exponential random variables. Unfortunately though, I can't really avoid looping, as each generated random variable depends on the previous one so I think vectorisation is out of the question. There are some calculations that I do around the generation, but the bottleneck (at present) is the generation. At this point I am assuming N will be large (N >= 1,000,000).

Here is some example code:

```
N <- 1e7
#Preallocate
x <- rep(0, times=N)

#Set a starting seed
x[1] <- runif(1)

for(i in 2:N) {
    #Do some calculations
    x[i] <- x[i-1] + rexp(1, x[i-1])  #Bottleneck
    #Do some more calculations
}
```

How can I speed this up? I've tried implementing in Rcpp, but it doesn't seem to do much in this case. Is there another clever way I can get around the `rexp()` call in each iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the fact that *if X ~ Exp(λ) then kX ~ Exp(λ/k)* [(source: Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Related_distributions) to speed up the code. This way we can do all the random draws with `rate = 1` up front and then just divide within the loop to scale them appropriately.

```
draws = rexp(N, rate = 1)
x <- rep(0, times = N)
x[1] <- runif(1)
for(i in 2:N) {
    #Do some calculations
    x[i] <- x[i-1] + draws[i] / x[i-1] 
    #Do some more calculations
}
```

A microbenchmark with `N = 1e6` values show this to be about 14x faster:

```
N <- 1e6
draws = rexp(N, rate = 1)
x <- rep(0, times = N)
x[1] <- runif(1)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    draw_up_front = {
        draws = rexp(N, rate = 1)
        for (i in 2:N)
            x[i] <- x[i - 1] + draws[i] / x[i - 1]
    },
    draw_one_at_time = {
        for (i in 2:N)
            x[i] <- x[i - 1] + rexp(1, x[i - 1])
    },
    times = 10
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#              expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#     draw_up_front  153.9547  156.6552  159.9622  160.1901  161.9803  167.2831    10  a 
#  draw_one_at_time 2207.1997 2212.0460 2280.1265 2236.5197 2332.9913 2478.5104    10   b
```

Comment: Hm... interesting. I will try this out and see how it goes. Thanks for the response.

Comment: If you're not putting all the function in the benchmark, that's cheating.

Answer (score 3):

A brute-force Rcpp solution:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector genExp(int N) {

  NumericVector res(N);
  double prev;

  res[0] = unif_rand();
  for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
    prev = res[i-1];
    res[i] = prev + exp_rand() / prev;
  }

  return res;
}
```

Microbenchmark with `N = 1e6`:

```
Unit: milliseconds
             expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
    draw_up_front  167.17031  168.57345  170.62292  170.18072  171.73782  175.46868    20
 draw_one_at_time 1415.01898 1465.57139 1510.81220 1502.15753 1550.07829 1623.70831    20
             rcpp   28.25466   29.33682   33.52528   29.89636   30.74908   94.38009    20
```

With `N = 1e7`:

```
Unit: milliseconds
          expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 draw_up_front 1698.730 1708.739 1737.8633 1716.1345 1752.3276 1923.3940    20
          rcpp  297.142  319.794  338.6755  327.6626  364.6308  398.1554    20
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have used this answer to aid in speeding up my code, however the real progress was due to Gregor's answer above, so have accepted that one.